# Prevent double tap from selecting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have made a jQuery mobile widget which has a minus button on the left and a plus button on the right and a div in the middle with a number which gets updated after either the plus or minus buttons is pushed. It's essentially just a "quantity" selector.

The problem is that when either button is pressed too frequently (if you wanted to add a couple of items quickly) then it selects other text on the page, as in the screenshot.

Can anyone think of a way of preventing this?

[image]

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

For more information you can also check this answer: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css#4407335)

Answer (score 2):

You have to prevent text selection in your buttons :

Here is a cross-compatible CSS class

```
.noselect {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

And add this class to all your element you want to not be selectable.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Cohen, but I marked the other answer as correct because it provided a link to the source.

Comment: Hmm ok, I will remember to provide the source for the next time